# Remove embedded line-feeds from fields of a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file in which a single row is getting split into multiple rows.

The source file contents are:

```
"ID","BotName"
"1","ABC"
"2","CDEF"
"3","AAA
XYZ"
"4",
"ABCD"
```

As we can see, IDs `3` and `4` are getting split into multiple rows. So, is there any way in Python to join those rows with the previous line?

Desired output:

```
"ID","BotName"
"1","ABC"
"2","CDEF"
"3","AAAXYZ"
"4","ABCD"
```

This the code I have:

```py
data = open(r"C:\Users\suksengupta\Downloads\BotReport_V01.csv","r")
```

Comment: I'm confused. Is the output what you get or what you would like to get? Ps. can you share a piece of code we can work on? :)

Comment: Share your code and the input file you want to append.

Comment: Currently I am below code to read the file

    data = open(r"C:\Users\suksengupta\Downloads\BotReport_V01.csv","r")



The output mentioned above I would like to get

Comment: @Sukanta, edit your post and append the code you are using.

Comment: find a regex removing new lines after a coma or not a double-quote.

Comment: open your file with notepad or an ide editor and paste the output here, looks like you need to remove any newline returns within the speech marks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like your `CSV` file has control characters embedded in the fields contents. If that is the case, you need to strip them out in order to have each field contents printed joined together.

With that in mind, something like this will fix the problem:

```py
import re

src = r'C:\Users\suksengupta\Downloads\BotReport_V01.csv'

with open(src) as f:
    data = re.sub(r'([\w|,])\s+', r'\1', f.read())

print(data)
```

The above code will result in the output below printed to console:

```
"ID","BotName"
"1","ABC"
"2","CDEF"
"3","AAAXYZ"
"4","ABCD"
```

Comment: I tried the above code but it will append all the lines into one line.

Comment: Can you post an **exact** sample of your input file? Maybe link it somewhere I can download it.

Comment: The file is in exact the format I have mentioned above

Comment: Alright. Just posted an alternative solution and that one seems to cover all cases. Check it out.

Comment: @Sukanta, did you test it?